# How can I open an unverified pkg file on Mac?

Tags: macos-catalina, pkg-file

I just got a new Mac Catalina. I'm trying to install git and it's giving me issues. I downloaded git-osx-installer from here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/

It download as "git-2.15.0-intel-universal-mavericks.pkg".

When I double-click on it to install it, it tells me: "git-2.15.0-intel-universal-mavericks.pkg" cannot be opened because it is from an unidentified developer. macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware.

How can I open this package? I'm pretty sure it's legit. I started at git-scm.com/downloads, clicked on Mac OS X, and clicked on Tim Harper's installer for Git to get to sourceforge.net. Is this not the official source for downloading git for Mac?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you searched for the solution?

Comment: Right-click and select open.